# tidyr separate function delimiters to avoid repetition

Tags: r, tidyr

I have been using tidyr to separate some text into columns.

### The input

```
Mypathcolon <- data.frame(c("1 Hospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust\nHospital Number: H2890235\nPatient Name:  al-Bilal, Widdad\nDOB:  1922-05-04\nGeneral Practitioner: Dr. Mondragon, Amber\nDate received:  2002-11-10\nClinical Details:  Previous had serrated lesions ?,If looks more like UC, please provide Nancy severity index\n3 specimen. Nature of specimen:  Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'Ascending colon x2 '|,Nature of specimen as stated on request form = 'rectum'|,Nature of specimen as stated on pot = '4X LOWER, 4X UPPER OESOPHAGUS '|,Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'rectal polyp '|\nMacroscopic description: 1 specimens collected the largest measuring 3 x 5 x 2 mm and the smallest 3 x 5 x 5 mm\nHistology:  The appearances are of a hyperplastic polyp.,8 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4."))

names(Mypathcolon)<-c("PathReportWhole")
```

### The function

```
Histoltree  <- c("Hospital Number:","Patient Name:",
   "DOB:","General Practitioner:","Date received:",
   "Clinical Details","Nature of specimen",
   "Macroscopic description:","Histology","Diagnosis")

Mypathcolon %>% 
   tidyr::separate(PathReportWhole, 
   into = c("added_name",Histoltree), 
     sep = paste(Histoltree, collapse = "|"))
```

### The current output

This gives me the column names

```
 [1] "added_name"               "Hospital Number:"         "Patient Name:"            "DOB:"                    
 [5] "General Practitioner:"    "Date received:"           "Clinical Details"         "Nature of specimen"      
 [9] "Macroscopic description:" "Histology"                "Diagnosis"
```

However the data in the columns from "Nature of specimen" to "Diagnosis" actually contains the text from "Nature of specimen" to "Nature of specimen" in the text instead of "Nature of specimen" to "Macroscopic description" as it should be: see below for the actual output:

```
structure(list(added_name = "1 Hospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust\n", 
    `Hospital Number:` = " H2890235\n", `Patient Name:` = "  al-Bilal, Widdad\n", 
    `DOB:` = "  1922-05-04\n", `General Practitioner:` = " Dr. Mondragon, Amber\n", 
    `Date received:` = "  2002-11-10\n", `Clinical Details` = ":  Previous had serrated lesions ?,If looks more like UC, please provide Nancy severity index\n3 specimen. ", 
    `Nature of specimen` = ":  ", `Macroscopic description:` = " as stated on pot = 'Ascending colon x2 '|,", 
    Histology = " as stated on request form = 'rectum'|,", Diagnosis = " as stated on pot = '4X LOWER, 4X UPPER OESOPHAGUS '|,"), .Names = c("added_name", 
"Hospital Number:", "Patient Name:", "DOB:", "General Practitioner:", 
"Date received:", "Clinical Details", "Nature of specimen", "Macroscopic description:", 
"Histology", "Diagnosis"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

How can I force the function to extract the columns between the listed delimiters as opposed to what it seems to be doing which is to repetitively extract.

### The desired output

```
Hospital: Random NHS Foundation Trust\n
Hospital Number: H2890235\n
Patient Name:  al-Bilal, Widdad\n
DOB:  1922-05-04\n
General Practitioner: Dr. Mondragon, Amber\n
Date received:  2002-11-10\n
Clinical Details:  Previous had serrated lesions ?,If looks more like UC, please provide Nancy severity index\n3 specimen. 
Nature of specimen:  Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'Ascending colon x2 '|,Nature of specimen as stated on request form = 'rectum'|,Nature of specimen as stated on pot = '4X LOWER, 4X UPPER OESOPHAGUS '|,Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'rectal polyp '|\n
Macroscopic description: 1 specimens collected the largest measuring 3 x 5 x 2 mm and the smallest 3 x 5 x 5 mm\n
Histology:  The appearances are of a hyperplastic polyp.,8 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4.
```

Answer (score 1):

After your revision, I could see what you wanted. The key here is to split stings with two patterns. Then, you want to create a data frame. `cSplit()` in the `splitstackshape` package can split strings with a separator (i.e., `:`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)
library(splitstackshape)

# Convert factor to character

Mypathcolon$PathReportWhole <- as.character(Mypathcolon$PathReportWhole)

# Split the string at two specific points, create a data frame,
# assign a column name, split strings

temp <- stri_split_regex(str = Mypathcolon$PathReportWhole, pattern = "\\n(?=[A-Z])|\\.\\s(?=.*:)") %>%
        as.data.frame %>%
        setNames("foo") %>%
        cSplit("foo", sep = ":", direction = "wide", type.convert = FALSE) 


                      foo_1
 1:              1 Hospital
 2:         Hospital Number
 3:            Patient Name
 4:                     DOB
 5:    General Practitioner
 6:           Date received
 7:        Clinical Details
 8:      Nature of specimen
 9: Macroscopic description
10:               Histology

foo_2
 1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Random NHS Foundation Trust
 2:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             H2890235
 3:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     al-Bilal, Widdad
 4:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1922-05-04
 5:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Dr. Mondragon, Amber
 6:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           2002-11-10
 7:                                                                                                                                               Previous had serrated lesions ?,If looks more like UC, please provide Nancy severity index\n3 specimen
 8: Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'Ascending colon x2 '|,Nature of specimen as stated on request form = 'rectum'|,Nature of specimen as stated on pot = '4X LOWER, 4X UPPER OESOPHAGUS '|,Nature of specimen as stated on pot = 'rectal polyp '|
 9:                                                                                                                                                               1 specimens collected the largest measuring 3 x 5 x 2 mm and the smallest 3 x 5 x 5 mm
10:                                                                                                                                                            The appearances are of a hyperplastic polyp.,8 pieces of tissue, the largest measuring 4.
```

Comment: Hi @jazzurro. The question has been amended to also show the desired output. I want the Histology to show the text between Histology and Diagnosis and the Macroscopic description colum to show the text between 'Macroscopic description' and 'Histology' etc. At the moment the Histology column shows text between 'Nature of specimen' and the next 'Nature of specimen'

Comment: @SebastianZeki Thanks for your message. I had a look of your expected outcome, but that dput was not clear to me. Would it be possible for you to clearly show what you expect? I did have a hard time to think what you want for Macroscopic, Histology, and diagnosis. If I am not mistaken, you do not have diagnosis in the original data. Can you clarify if this is the case?

Comment: @SebastianZeki I converted your expected outcome to long format and checked what you expect.  I have `Nature of specimen` in `Macroscopic description`, `Histology`, and `Diagnosis`. But the rest of the texts are matching with what you are expecting in the desired output, if I am not mistaken. Can you double check your desired output? I would not revise my code till I have your reply.

Comment: Hi @jazzurro. Yes teh rest of the text is fine. It is just the columns Nature of specimen in Macroscopic description, Histology, and Diagnosis that have the incorrect text in your example

Comment: @SebastianZeki I trimmed my code a bit. That was enough to have the output. If necessary, remove the first row in the output.

Comment: @jazzuro I get Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 11, 12

Comment: @SebastianZeki I double checked my code, and it is working with your sample data. Hence, I do not know what is causing the issue on your side. The only thing that I can do for you is that I can tell there is something wrong with the number of row when you were doing something. If you have run my code with other data, you want to check your data.